# Executing Commands in CMD and accessing a git on-premises server

Tags: c#, git, cmd

I have configured password less auth for my git on-premises. Now I want to first go to the ssh dir in local machine and then access the git server from there all using cmd. I am doing this whole thing using C# code. Below is my code.

```cs
        ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = null;
        Process process = null;
        Process main = null;
        ProcessStartInfo processMainInfo = null;


        processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe","ssh swx@192.168.12.232");
        processStartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        processStartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Users\xyz\.ssh";

        process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo = processStartInfo;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        process.Start();
        process.StandardInput.WriteLine("/c cd git_home && git log");


        string returnValue = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
```

I  know that /c first executes the and then terminates. I tried to use && for the whole command like this :

```sh
> ssh swx@192.168.12.232 && cd git_home && git log
```

but in this case only `ssh swx@192.168.12.232` this part is getting executed and the other `cd git_home && git log` are not.

Can anyone help me here?

My main goal here is to execute two commands one after another 1st :

```sh
> ssh swx@192.168.12.232
```

this should get executed it will give me access to the server form the cmd and after that

```sh
> cd git_home && git log
```

which will get me to the git repo and give me all the logs as output in string returnValue.

or if there is some more efficient way pls suggest.

**Edit**

I tried to run the commands one after another below is the code:

```
            Process p = new Process();
        ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
        info.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        info.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        info.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        info.UseShellExecute = false;

        p.StartInfo = info;
        p.Start();

        using (StreamWriter sw = p.StandardInput)
        {
            if (sw.BaseStream.CanWrite)
            {
                sw.WriteLine(" C:");
                sw.WriteLine(@"cd C:\Users\xyz\.ssh");
                sw.WriteLine(" ssh swx@192.168.12.232");
                sw.WriteLine("cd git_home");
                sw.WriteLine("git log");

            }
            string aaa = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        }
```

But the string aaa returns :

```
    Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.1023]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

D:\Kovair Projects\Adapters\KOVAIR_Git_KovairGitAdapter_2.20 - EventService-BAK\Source\TestAPP\bin> C:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE>cd C:\Users\xyz\.ssh

C:\Users\xyz\.ssh> ssh swx@192.168.12.232

C:\Users\xyz\.ssh>cd git_home

C:\Users\xyz\.ssh>git log

C:\Users\xyz\.ssh>
```

what can I do so that I can execute the last 2 commands in the linux server?

Comment: You need to pass "cd git_home && git log" as a *single string* to the `ssh` process.  Are you ssh-ing to a Linux machine or a Windows machine?

Comment: @TimRoberts to a Linux machine ya I figured that out but I am not able to achieve it. Can you suggest me a way?

Comment: `"ssh swx@192.168.12.232 'cd git_home ; git log'"`

Comment: @TimRoberts I didn't get your point can we put this whole as an argument?

Comment: Yes, that's what you pass to `ProcessStartInfo`.  The inside string becomes a single parameter to `ssh`.

Comment: @TimRoberts no its not working 
when executing "ssh swx@192.168.12.232 'cd git_home ; git log'" I am getting this error 
 bash: cd git_home ; git log: command not found

C:\Users\rock\.ssh>

and "ssh swx@192.168.12.232  && 'cd git_home ; git log'"
is getting executed But It takes me to the ssh server only

Comment: If you `ssh` in by hand, can you run `git?

Comment: @TimRoberts Yes I even tried to run the whole command by hand in cmd

Comment: I'm not sure what to tell you.  That's the correct syntax.  If you type that exact line at a command prompt, it should work.

Comment: @TimRoberts the command should be ssh swx@192.168.12.232 "cd git_home ; git log"
you already mentioned it before but your your command was missing " (double quotes).
and thanks for your effort and time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

swx@192.168.12.232 "cd git_home ; git log" execute this command this might help.